# Clear form after redux action succeeds

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm storing my form inputs in React component `state`. When I submit the form, I trigger a Redux action. And when this action succeeds, I want to update the state again - to clear the form. But how to do it?

I mean, I can easily store form state in Redux too and everything will be resolved, but I'd prefer to store component specific things in component state.

Comment: do you want to update state as soon as you trigger the action?

Comment: No, I think its better to wait until the action succeeds @MuraliPrasanth

Comment: then go ahead and put it in componentWillReceiveProps if previous state and next state are different.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using something like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to delay the dispatching until the API call succeeds:

```
const postForm = data => dispatch => fetch(...).then((...) => dispatch(...))
```

Since `fetch` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can then wait until it's resolved (api call succeeded) before performing the form clearing in your component:

```
props.postForm(...)
  .then(() => this.setState(<clear the form state>))
  .catch(<do something to warn the user api call failed?>)
```

Answer (score 1):

What does that action update on the state exactly?

One way would be to add an extra case in your componentWillReceiveProps that handle that update of the form. If the action let say updates the list, you could have something like the following on your componentWillReceiveProps method inside you component:

```html
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.list !== this.props.list) {
    this.setState({
      formFields: this.getNewClearFormFields()
    })
  }
}
```

Where getNewClearFormFields is a function that returns your new form fields

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the `state` after `redux action` succeeds, then I would suggest go ahead and put it in `componentWillReceiveProps` by comparing `prevState` and `nextState`

use `mapStateToProps()` to map `redux state` to `component`
and then update the component state like below

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      ...
    });
  }
```

Comment: This will only work if the affected redux state is connected to the component.